# Little or lesser-known multi-day hike routes

Tags: hiking, backpacking, alpine

I have just finished part of this http://www.peaksofthebalkans.com/index.php?lang=en and cannot recommend it highly enough. Aside from the beautiful mountains, another great aspect of the trip was that we met probably only around 15 other hikers in 6 full days making it feel even more remote. Does anyone have any good suggestions for similar things? I.e. a long distance hike route which is not very well known, or perhaps a mountain range with a hut network that could be used to construct a multi-day route. Does not have to be in Europe.

EDIT: Following on from the first few comments below, I'm not looking for loads of information or a trip report or anything, just a lead, a place name, or a link to a map, etc. :)

Comment: If you ask on SX and you are getting an insider tip, it won't stay an insiders' tip. You know, this network is quite famous and attracts lots of people... :)

Comment: I was expecting this comment... So one thing that was interesting about the route that I link to above is that, other than the map that you can buy that the site talks of, there is very little other information around online. Your average hiker is not going to commit to a trip where there isn't much information about it. Furthermore, a comment that I'm sure is also coming in people's replies is that many well known hike routes are not that busy, and I would also be interested to hear of suggestions of those. This is more of a discussion starter than a question, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

would you look at visiting as far a field as New Zealand.

Lots of trips, lots of information online - Its possible to do 10+ days and not see another person if you choose the trip and the time of year carefully. We have a vast track and hut network (In our terms a track can be nothing more than markers nailed to trees or cairns on a mountain side. A hut can be a corrugated iron 'tent' with a dirt floor and no door though to a facility with heating, cooking, bunks and mattresses, very few have power)

You will need to filter out the most popular trips that target tourists, and many well known ones if you want the "alone" experience.

Comment: Vast hut network and New Zealand Alps... sounds good, will look into it!

Answer (score 4):

How about [Via Dinarica](http://viadinarica.com), virtually no information and similar experience in another neck of the Balkans. Three trails, each about 650 km - still more of an idea than established project. Part of it overlaps with the [Peaks of the Balkans route](http://zbulo.org/peaks-of-the-balkans/).

Comment: I would definitely consider returning to the region, thanks for this.

Comment: In Montenegro there's two long distance hiking trails, the [Coastal Transversal](http://www.balkansgeotourism.travel/content/wilderness-hiking-biking-montenegro/see9C970FC56083A0BC8) running North-South from Orjen at the border with Croatia to Taraboshi in Albania. The second is CT-1 starting at the coast and finishing inlnad, it stems from Yugoslavia times and was supported by a hut system now in disrepair, it still can be followed. 
Similar to the Peaks of the Balkans there is the [Shar Planina Traverse](https://goo.gl/loLYjI) under development connecting Macedonia with Albanian and Kosovo

Answer (score 2):

Many areas in Scotland can be quite quiet, especially outside the peak season. There are also many [long distance walks](http://www.walkhighlands.co.uk/long-distance-routes.shtml) ranging from the well known to the less so. I've heard the Rob Roy way and the Cape Wrath trail are quiet good although I've actually done neither.

There is no system of manned mountain huts like in many places but many unmanned [bothies](http://www.mountainbothies.org.uk/locationmap.asp) which can be used and you can wild camp in most places.

Another possibility is the [Tatra mounatins](http://www.discoverzakopane.com/hiking.html) on the Poland Slovakia border. There is a good network of huts but they aren't that remote (and were reasonably busy) but are not well known (at least in the UK).

Comment: I've heard good things about the Tatras before, and Scotland is a good suggestion (for me personally I've done enough hiking in the UK and so would rather go elsewhere to higher peaks, but for others seeing this question this may be useful)